# Find Fragment in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I got a fragment which contains a fragment, and I want to do stuff with it in onViewCreated or onCreateView. How can I find that inner fragment?

Here is the containerfragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            tools:context="xx.activity.fragment.SalesFragment">
<fragment android:id="@+id/fragment_category"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/priceEdit"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:name="xxfragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_category"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It is not possible to find that inner fragment_category with the FragmentManager

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
CategoryFragment catFrag = (CategoryFragment) 
fm.findFragmentByTag(CategoryFragment.ID);
```

returns null.

Do I have to get the FragmentManager to know, that there is another fragment, or are there other possibilities to find that CategoryFragment?

Comment: try `fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_category)`

Comment: No, that also doesn't work...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may need to use the [child FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) up to API 28, or the [androidx child FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) afterwards to interact with nested fragments.

```
FragmentManager fm = parentFragment.getChildFragmentManager();
```

Comment: Yup this is availabel in sdk 17+.

Comment: Yepp, that works. Didn't know that there are other FragmentManager than that one from the activity. Thank you!